# setting margins on relative layout doesnt work

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, margins

I used a FragmentTransaction to add a Fragment into a FrameLayout.  I want to dynamically change the margin of the RelativeLayout used by the Fragment. However, the margins are not changing with RelativeLayout.layoutParams.  I also used `setMargins()` and it didnt work.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infocard, container, false);

        RelativeLayout infoLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.info);
        infoLayout.setOnClickListener(new EmptyClickListener());

        final int width = 250;
        final int height = 320;
        int leftMargin = 0;
        int topMargin = 0;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

        if (x - width < 0) {
            leftMargin = 0;
            System.out.println("left " + leftMargin);
        }
        else {
            leftMargin = x - width;
        }

        if (y >= 450 && y <= 480) {
            topMargin = y - height;
        }

        params.leftMargin = leftMargin;
        params.topMargin = topMargin;

        infoLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams
```

instead of

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
```

Layouts expect the params type to be the type from their parent container rather than the View type that you are setting them on

Comment: For some reason, this works on a Toshiba tab running 3.2.1, however, it doesnt work on the Kindle Fire 2.3.4

Comment: Is it throwing any errors? Have you tried it the other way on the KF (the way you posted) to see if maybe its backwards?

Comment: It is not throwing any errors. The way I posted didnt work on the kindle fire.

Comment: Strange. It may have something to do with some changes to the OS that were made for the KF.. I'm not really sure, though. The way I posted is correct and is what Android expects. If its not working then maybe try cleaning your project, uninstalling the one currently on the device, and reinstalling (just to exhaust all possibilities). If it still happens it's likely down to something specific to the way KF handles LayoutParams.

Comment: I made a new post specific to Kindle Fire if anyone can solve this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813894/setting-margins-on-relativelayout-doesnt-work-on-kindle-fire